# Trying to scale an HTML table with multiple <a>

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape a table from a website with a table having multiple entries in the  tags - but it keeps giving me an index out of range for the specific column, any thoughts on how I can do this differently?

https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_chr/lau2019.htm

```
for row in table_body.find_all('tr'):
    # Find all data in each column
    columns = row.find_all('td')
    if (columns != []):
        id = columns[0].text.strip()
        date = columns[1].text.strip()
        payload = columns[2].a.contents[0:].strip('&0.')
        lv = columns[3].a.contents[0].strip('&0.')
        site = columns[4].text.strip()
        remark = columns[5].text.strip()
df = df.append({'ID': id, 'Date': date, 'Payload(s)': payload, 'Launch Vehicle': lv, 'Site': site, 'Remark': site},ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv('GunterPage.csv',index=True)
```

Comment: which line of code is giving the error?

Comment: payload = columns[2].a.contents[0:].strip('&0.')